# how to change a php variable into a int then add 50 to it for reuse

Tags: php

How to I change the height variable into a numeric value so I can add 50 to it and reuse it?

```
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($img);
```

Comment: The value you receive in your code should be numeric. But you can always use `$height = intval($height);`.

Comment: I though it was but Im not able to apply math but thanks ill try tht

Comment: That worked couldn't remember that intval(), had trouble finding it too. I don't know if the $height wasn't a int though since I was apply a couple functions to it after. Thank You .

Comment: you can also cast a variable as integer, eg $height = (int)$height + 50;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).
`getimagesize()` returns an array of values, where index `0` and `1` contain numeric representations of width and height of your image.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer, but a useful aside (using answer so that code is formatted).

If you are unsure about the datatypes of variables or the returns from functions you can use `var_dump`.

For example, you might:

```
var_dump( getimagesize( $img ) );
```

Which would return something like:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(2560)
  [1]=>
  int(1024)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(26) "width="2560" height="1024""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(8)
  ["channels"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

This tells you that indexes 0 and 1 are already `int` values.